# Boldfaced line numbers in critical apparatus with Sanskrit script

Tags: indic, reledmac

I am making a critical edition that has some Sanskrit text in which I would like the numbers in the critical apparatus referring to the line numbers in the text to be bold.  The problem is that the Sanskrit font I am using, Nakula, has no boldfaced form.  How can I, for example, use the default LaTeX Roman script for the line numbers in the critical apparatus? How do I reset the font that is used for the line numbers in the critical apparatus?  You can get the Devanagari font, Nakula, [here](http://bombay.indology.info/software/fonts/devanagari/).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
    \newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Nakula}


\begin{document}

\Xnotenumfont{\bfseries}

\noindent This is an edition of the \emph{Samādhirājasūtra}.

\vspace{30pt}

\beginnumbering
    \autopar

\devanagarifont
\begin{sanskrit}
\noindent तत्र \edtext{खलु}{\Afootnote{A; एव B}} भगवान् पुनरपि चन्द्रप्रभं बोधिसत्वमामन्त्रायते स्म॥
 तस्मात् तर्हि कुमार बोधिसत्वेन महासत्वेन सर्वधर्मानां महाभिज्ञापरिकर्म परिशोधयितुकेमनायं समाधिः श्रोतव्यः॥

\end{sanskrit}

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\Xnotenumfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FakeBold`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Nakula}[
  BoldFont=Nakula,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=4},
]


\begin{document}

\Xnotenumfont{\bfseries}

\noindent This an edition of the \emph{Samādhirājasūtra}.

\vspace{30pt}

\beginnumbering
    \autopar

\devanagarifont
\begin{sanskrit}
\noindent तत्र \edtext{खलु}{\Afootnote{A; एव B}} भगवान् पुनरपि चन्द्रप्रभं बोधिसत्वमामन्त्रायते स्म॥
 तस्मात् तर्हि कुमार बोधिसत्वेन महासत्वेन सर्वधर्मानां महाभिज्ञापरिकर्म परिशोधयितुकेमनायं समाधिः श्रोतव्यः॥

\end{sanskrit}

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `fakebold`.  The best solution would be to use the standard LaTeX font, though, as the `fakebold` bold font is a little too bold.  There is an option in `reledmac` to change the font of the line numbers, but I'm not sure how to use it:

"Line numbers for the main text are usually printed in a smaller font in the margin.
The \numlabfont macro is provided as a standard name for that font: it is initially defined as
\newcommand{\numlabfont}{\normalfont\scriptsize}"